# How does one replace only the three first octects of an IP address in Perl

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, regex

My target is to replace only the three first digits in IP address with new IP address 
For example

```
 NEW three first three digits – 17.100.10
 OLD three first three digits - 12.200.10 
 Existing IP address in file  - 12.200.10.2
```

Then I will get the new IP as **17.100.10.2**

So I write the following Perl command in order to perform the replace action

But the problem is that if the NEW IP matches the three last digits then it will replace them also

So

What need to change in my Perl command in order to replace only the three first digits in IP address?

Real Example1 that described the problem:

```
export OLD_IP=192.9.1
export NEW_IP=172.192.9
```

.

```
echo 1.192.9.1 | perl -i -pe 'next if /^ *#/; s/(\b|\D)$ENV{OLD_IP}(\b|\D)/$1$ENV      {NEW_IP}$2/g'  
 1.172.192.9
```

.

Comment: Modify OLD _IP=192.9.1 and NEW_IP=172.192.9 so that they include the 3rd dot ie OLD _IP=192.9.1. and NEW_IP=172.192.9. (dots might have to be escaped, depending on your scripting langage/regex engine).

Comment: an IP is a 32 bit number arranged into 4 octets. just convert it to an int and manipulate the upper 24 bits, then convert back.

Comment: @Olipro - I need to replace allot of IP's in many files , for example it is possible to find and replace like 100 IP's in one file , so I not think your solution is relevant here

Comment: yael - your comment on Olipro's comment is wrong. He's not suggesting that you do the conversion, he's suggesting that you write your Perl script to do that. "Smarter, not harder."

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/perl

my @ip = split('\.', $old_ip);
$ip[0] = 172;
$ip[1] = 16;
$ip[2] = 0;
$new_ip = join(".", @ip);
```

**OR**

```
#!/bin/perl

my @ip = split('\.', $old_ip);
$new_ip = '172.16.0.' . $ip[3];
```

**OR**

```
s/(\d{1,3}\.){3}(?=(\d+$))/$ENV{new_ip}/
```

For the single line, WTF, version; that should drop into your shell script...

```
# export new_ip=172.168.0.
# echo 192.168.5.6 | perl -i pe 's/(\d{1,3}\.){3}(?=(\d+$))/$ENV{new_ip}/'
172.16.0.6
```

Comment: please advice how to combine your solution in my perl syntax ? , ( I need to run the perl one line in my ksh script )

Comment: your solution change all IP's in file , But I need to match  only the required "OLD_IP" and to change only the "OLD_IP" not all IP's in file , the target is to change three first digits of marched OLD_IP , EXAMPLE - perl -i -pe 's/(\d{1,3}\.){3}(?=(\d+$))/$ENV{new_ip}/' $FILE

Comment: Server Fault is for Professional System Administrators (et al) only. This is **not** a "I can haz teh cod3z" site. It should be fairly obvious from the code where it is matching the old IP and replacing it with the new one. If you can't figure it out, please refer to [Perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for a complete guide.

Answer (score 3):

That's only one of the three problems your code has. The other two are:

- Your code changes `192.9.100.1` (with OLD_IP=192.9.1) to `172.192.900.1` (with NEW_IP=172.192.9).
- Your code changes `192.101.1.2` (with OLD_IP=192.1.1) to `172.192.9.1.2` (with NEW_IP=172.192.9).

Solution:

```
perl -pe's/(?<![\d.])\Q$ENV{OLD_IP}\E(?=\.\d)/$ENV{NEW_IP}/g'
```

Notes:

- `^` would be even better than `(?<![\d.])` if IP addresses are always at the start of a line. (The `/g` would become useless.)
- `(?<!\S)` would be even better than `(?<![\d.])` if IP addresses are always preceded by a space, tab or are always found at the start of line.

Comment: I think you need `(?<![\d.])` instead of `(?<!\d)`, otherwise you'll still have exactly the same problem as described in the question.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen, That's not true. Go ahead, try it.

Comment: Ah, right, you avoid it because you require a trailing period.  But try it with just `OLD_IP=192.9` and `NEW_IP=172.192`.  (OK, the question does specify _three_ octets, so I guess your solution _is_ correct.)

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen, And it doesn't wash my socks either. But fine, I'll add it. But it still won't handle `OLD_IP=192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

If each IP address appears on a line of its own, this is easy:

```
s/^\Q$ENV{OLD_IP}\E/$ENV{NEW_IP}/mg
```

If not, you can use a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
s/(?<![\d.])\Q$ENV{OLD_IP}\E/$ENV{NEW_IP}/g
```

This will match and replace the string given in `OLD_IP`, except when it follows a digit or a period.

**Edit:** To fix the issue pointed out by ikegami, you should also ensure that the matched string is not followed by a digit:

```
s/(?<![\d.])\Q$ENV{OLD_IP}\E(?!\d)/$ENV{NEW_IP}/g
```

Unlike ikegami's solution, this will work for any number of octets, not just three or fewer.